# Google Crawl rate & the log file mystery

Tags: apache, googlebot, apache-log-files, crawl-rate, technical-seo

According to Google Search Console for a website I am working on, Googlebot crawls ~5000 pages per day (min 2500, max 8500).

However, when looking at the Apache log files, GoogleBot only shows up ~10 times per day ...

For example:

```
66.249.64.88    [22/Jan/2020:15:09:01   +0100]  [22/Jan/2020:15:09:01 +0100]    GET / HTTP/1.1  200 1358    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

It is GoogleBot since doing a reverse dns does point to Google servers:

```
$ host 66.249.64.88
88.64.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-64-88.googlebot.com
```

But I am wondering : If GoogleBot appears only 10 times in Apache log files while it crawls 5000 pages per day, where are the remaining 4990 crawls going?

How can I know which resource GoogleBot crawls when it does not appear in the log files ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The value Google is showing (~5000) it's how much they "set aside" to crawl your website, based on what they think it'll be needed - it doesn't mean they will use it or even that there's a need for this much.

If your website isn't large and/or doesn't get to much organic traffic, having 10 visits per day isn't unheard-of.

Look into **which** pages are being visited instead; if important pages are not getting crawled then, yes, you have a problem.

Comment: Well yes I think there is a problem: 90% of GoogleBot entries show a 404 when trying to access the robots.txt. However, the robots.txt is directly accessible from root and it does return a 200, I checked with curl --head ... And apart from the homepage, Googlebot accesses very few other pages / resources in 2 weeks, like 2 or 3 product pages ...

Comment: Yeah, it does look like you are having some issues - depending on the size of your website, it can be some sort of "crawler trap":

https://www.searchenginejournal.com/crawler-traps-causes-solutions-prevention/305781/